# Why does the string representation of User objects remain the same in my Django application?

Tags: django, django-authentication

I altered the User class in "/home/david/django/django/contrib/auth/models.py" as follows to override the string representation for a user in my Django application.

```
class User(models.Model):
    ...
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.get_profile().full_name()
```

I had written a function called `full_name()` in my user profile model to display full names the way I want them to be displayed.

However, after I restart Apache, I find that users in select menus of model forms are still represented by usernames. Why?

[image]

Comment: I'm a bit confused. I guess you didn't alter the .../auth/models.py file of your django installation because that would obviously be a bad idea. If that is the case you are trying to overwrite the native models.py file of django.contrib.auth. But AFAIK such a custom overwriting only works with templates not with python files.

Comment: Thank you, I actually am trying to alter the native .../auth/models.py file of my Django installation to override how users are represented. What do you mean by templates?

Comment: Are you sure, that this is the django installation that your project uses?

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to monkey patch you installation. It really is a bad idea.

You can [read here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) how you can override the way a model choice form field shows its model instances.

In you case it would look something like this:

```
class UserChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.get_profile().full_name()
```

Then use this field in your forms. In a model form you will have to override the default field that is used.